# Filling image in the text in PDF using PDF internal structure

Tags: pdf, svg, pdf-generation

In one of my application they are creating PDF from SVG. To construct PDF they are constructing buffer as PDF internal structure tree( header, body,xref table,trailer etc). In SVG I have tspan element which has fill attribute with URl of image pattern.
I am using below PDF internal structure for filling text with image but I am getting blank PDF page. The image is jpeg image. please help me to resolve the issue.

```
15 0 obj 
<< /Type /Pattern 
/PatternType 1 
/PaintType 1 
/TilingType 1 
/BBox [0 0 60 60] 
/XStep 60 
/YStep 60 
/Resources 16 0 R 
/Length 12 
>> 
stream
q
/img1 Do
endstream
Q

BT 
/F1 1 Tf 
1 0 0 -1 0 0 Tm 
0 0 0 1 K
15.0 W
0 J
0 0 0 1 k
BX /ca0 gs EX
(HELLO) Tj 
/Pattern cs 
/P1 scn 
0 0 TD 
(HELLO) Tj 
ET
```

Comment: Is `img1` a bitmap image? Then your code draws it in the lower left unit square of the pattern bbox. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: it is a jpeg image. I could not see text filled with image in the PDF.

Comment: @K J In PDF cant we pattern for stroked text also? I am using JPEG image, how to lay transparent pattern at its core? What color I need to use to lay  transparent pattern?

Comment: *"I could not see text filled with image in the PDF."* - Ok, in that case you just fill a single 1x1 square of the 60x60 pattern area. It's very likely that that little square is not inside any letter. You should scale your coordinate system (by means of a **cm** instruction) before showing the image (in `/img1 Do`).

Comment: @mkl, my jpeg image width is 610 and height is 458, what values I need to set for BBox, XSTep and YStep and cm scaling in pattern structure?

Comment: How large shall the image be on the page?

Comment: My PDF page size 1280x828. The image should be visible background of text only, outside of the text it should not be visible.

Comment: @mkl I need to apply background image for selected text. the length of the text can be anything. I used BBox as 0,0 610 458 and xstep as 610 and ystep as 458 and cm as 610 0 0 458 0 0 but still image is not visisble.

Comment: I see in your edited question `P1 scn`. I assume you mean `/P1 scn`. If that doesn't help, please share the whole PDF  for analysis.

Comment: @mkl I have shared the PDF file for the analysis. https://smallpdf.com/file#s=65497ccd-7ddf-48d8-9797-b9d57302705b

Comment: @mkl This is my image https://pasteboard.co/qmZchLKGiv4K.jpg

Comment: @mkl if you dont mind, have you got a chance to look into my PDF internal structure?

Comment: *"have you got a chance to look into my PDF internal structure?"* - yes, see my answer. There actually were multiple issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all and already discussed in comments, you draw a bitmap image in your pattern content stream

```
/img1 Do
```

without setting the current transformation matrix to scale it before. Thus, your image will be drawn in a 1×1 user space unit square (by default <sup>1</sup>/<sub>72</sub> in × <sup>1</sup>/<sub>72</sub> in). This surely is not what you want.

You already corrected this in the comments

> I used BBox as 0,0 610 458 and xstep as 610 and ystep as 458 and cm as 610 0 0 458 0 0 but still image is not visisble.

Looking for more issues, therefore, one finds in the file you shared:

1. In you text object you set graphics state parameters using

   ```
   BX /ca0 gs EX
   ```

   Looking up the **ca0** resource, one sees that this sets the *alpha* constant for non-stroking operations to 0. Thus, any following filling operations will be invisible! As you want to see the image you fill your text with, this is completely wrong. Use 1 instead of 0. If you actually want to reduce opaqueness, start with 1 and then reduce the value until the effect pleases you.
2. When adding the **cm** operation to your **Pattern** definition, you appear to have accidentally dropped the image drawing operation. Thus, add the image drawing operation again.
3. You use the same **Resources** dictionary for page and pattern. Apparently Adobe Acrobat does not like that. Thus, create a dedicated **Resources** dictionary for the pattern which then refers to the **XObject** dictionary from the page resources dictionary.

After these changes your PDF shows

[image: screenshot]

(BTW, the integrated PDF viewer in Chrome already was happy with only the first two changes...)

Comment: Thanks mkl.I will try your solutions. Could you please share the PDF file so that I can see the internal structure?

Comment: *"Could you please share the PDF file so that I can see the internal structure?"* - https://docdro.id/4pCPqH1

Comment: As you suggested, After changing the graphics state constant as 1, In the Ubuntu Document viewer Text with image is visible whereas in the integrated PDF viewer in Chrome the image is not visible. I shared the PDF file here https://smallpdf.com/file#s=c63e8206-fb44-4466-b520-b889fc6a325c please help me

Comment: If I open the PDF in Chrome and Firefox browser image is not visible whereas the image is visible in the PDF file you have shared. The PDF version is 1.4 for my file whereas  your PDF file version is 1.7.

Comment: In your new PDF you forgot the `0 Tr` before `0.00 0.00 Td
[(MERGE) ] TJ` in the page content stream. Thus, the thick border of the letter is again drawn by that **TJ**, covering the image. And by the way, the PDF version in the files you shared also is 1.7.

Comment: Thanks a lot mkl.It works in chrome after adding ) Tr.How to learn all these things?

Comment: *"How to learn all these things?"* - Most details of your issue - the missing scaling of the image, the activation of full transparency, the missing image drawing instruction, the missing text rendering mode instruction - are easy to see by simply going through the instructions, one-by-one, with the specification to look up details. Merely that the re-used resources dictionary might be a problem, is something you learn by analyzing many real world PDFs from different PDF producers.

Comment: The bottom portion of image is merging in text. How to make the top portion of image to be merged in text.

Comment: After setting Matrix as [1 0 0 -1 0 0], I am getting the result of  top portion of image is merged with text.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.